# Load big file asynchronously using c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

Hi I dnt have any knowledge on Multithreading or Parallel programing.

I need to load multiple file for an application, in which the load time does not affect the application or response to user.

I used [CreateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx) with that I cannot able to load data to a class variable.

Any guidance of how to do this in VC++ will be a great help.

Thanks in Advance !!

For example, 
My application is streaming content meantime I need to load a big image to to class variable (Bitmap), which should not affect the streaming i.e without pause.

Comment: this question does not deserve downvotes. it is actually nice question that shows the general confusion regarding the term "asynchronous". asynchronous does not imply always "on another thread". especially in IO, asynchronous IO DOES NOT utilizes threads in order to make the IO asynchronous. I suggest reading about Overlapped IO, IO completion ports and see examples from CPPRest and Boost.ASIO

Comment: @DavidHaim Thanks for the suggestions :)

Answer (score 2):

Modern C++ allows you to use hi level abstract features such as std::future:

```
  struct Data {
    // file name just for info
    std::string file_name;
    // here is data from file ...

    static Data load(const std::string& name) {
      Data data{ name };
      // todo load from file
      return std::move(data);
    }
  };
  std::vector<std::string> names = { "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt" };
  std::vector<std::future<Data>> results;
  for (const auto& name : names) {
    // load from the name file asynchronously 
    auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, &Data::load, std::ref(name));
    results.emplace_back(future);
  }
  // gather result
  for (auto& future : results) {
    Data& data = future.get();
    // todo use data from the file object
  }
```